# Descending order by price

Tags: python

NEW EDIT

the result is this when I only enter 1 coffee

```
Item: Juice Cost:  OrderCount: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Item: Coffee Cost:  OrderCount: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Item: Lemonade Cost:  OrderCount: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Item: Soda Cost:  OrderCount: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Item: Water Cost:  OrderCount: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
7% TAX:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                         -------                                                                                                                                                                                                          
TOTAL BALANCE:                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
--------------------------------
```

This is the relevant code snippet:

```
if totaldrinks > 0:
    print("DRINK")
    d = {}
    if coffee > 0:
        d['Coffee'] = (coffee, drink.count(countcoffee)) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
    if juice > 0:
        d['Juice'] = (juice, drink.count(countjuice)) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
    if soda > 0:
        d['Soda'] = (soda, drink.count(countsoda)) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
    if water > 0:
        d['Water'] = (water, drink.count(countwater)) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
    if lemonade > 0:
        d['Lemonade'] = (lemonade, drink.count(countlemonade)) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
    d_lst = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse = True)
    for item in d_lst:
        print("Item: %s Cost: $%.2f OrderCount: %i "%(item[0], item[1][0], item[1][1]))
```

Comment: Instead of posting your whole code, can you provide the relevant part only?

Comment: well I figured the whole code is needed for others to understand what the names are but yeah the relevant part is at the bottom of the code where it says cafe receipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is not properly indented. if I understand your question correctly the below code should do the job for you:

Create a dict:

```
d = {}

d['coffeec'] = (2.00, 2) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
d['juciec'] = (2.00, 1) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
d['sodac'] = (1.50, 10) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
d['waterc'] = (1.00, 20) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
d['lemonadec'] = (1.50, 10) # d[menu_item] = (cost, order_count)
```

so,

```
d = {'coffeec': (2.0, 2), 'waterc': (1.0, 20), 'lemonadec': (1.5, 10), 'juciec': (2.0, 1), 'sodac': (1.5, 10)}
```

Then reverse sort based on price:

```
d_lst = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1][0], reverse = True)
```

so, the new d_lst is as below:

```
d_lst = [('coffeec', (2.0, 2)), ('juciec', (2.0, 1)), ('lemonadec', (1.5, 10)), ('sodac', (1.5, 10)), ('waterc', (1.0, 20))]
```

Then iterate over your new d_lst to print the receipt:

```
>>> for item in d_lst:
...     print("Item:%s;;; Cost:%.2f;;; OrderCount:%i "%(item[0], item[1][0], item[1][1]))
...
Item:coffeec;;; Cost:2.00;;; OrderCount:2
Item:juciec;;; Cost:2.00;;; OrderCount:1
Item:lemonadec;;; Cost:1.50;;; OrderCount:10
Item:sodac;;; Cost:1.50;;; OrderCount:10
Item:waterc;;; Cost:1.00;;; OrderCount:20
```

Comment: it keeps printing the entire thing and add all the drinks when I only want to enter coffee.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete code based on your specific question, run it as is and reply if it achieves your specific task:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def main():
    #welcome statement
    print("Welcome to Deluxe Cafe")
    print("Please select by entering the selections from the menu below.")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    #drinks_dict: key = number;;; value = (name of the drink, cost, order_count)
    drinks_dict = {'1': ['Coffee', 2.00,0], '2': ['Juice', 2.00, 0], '3': ['Soda', 1.50, 0], '4': ['Water', 1.00, 0], '5': ['Lemonade', 1.50, 0]}
    #ask for customer input
    while True:
        for k,v in sorted(drinks_dict.items()):
            print("%s. %s  [%.2f]"%(k, v[0], v[1]))
        order = raw_input("Please enter your selection: ")

        if order in drinks_dict:
            print("1x %s added "%drinks_dict[order][0])
            drinks_dict[order][2] += 1
            more_orders = raw_input("Do you want to order more? yes or no\n")
            if more_orders == 'no':
                break
        else:
            print('Please type either: 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5')
    drinks_list = []
    drinks_list = sorted(drinks_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1], reverse = True)
    if drinks_list:
        print("Cafe Receipt")
        for item in drinks_list:
            if item[1][2] > 0:
                print("Item:%s;;; Cost:%.2f;;; OrderCount:%i "%(item[1][0], item[1][1], item[1][2]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```